# Making a simple card game in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

im working on making a really simple card game in python for school. It's as simple as two cards are drawn, one for the dealer and one for the user, and whoever gets the highest card wins that round. Every round won the users scores goes up by 1, and when the user fails a round his/her high scores is recorded to a .txt file alongside the .py file. Ive come into some what is probably very simple problems... one is when im choosing a random card for the dealer and user, and setting it to a variable, and the other is recording the score in the scores.txt file. Thanks for any help!!
It may be a bit messy but im more worried about it actually working. 
Here is the code:

```
from sys import argv # imports the opening of two separate files
import random # imports the 'random' string
script, filename = argv # sets two variables, one on the py file and the other on the txt file
txt = open(filename) # opens the txt file

# card variables assigning values 
Two = 1
Three = 2
Four = 3
Five = 4
Six = 5
Seven = 6
Eight = 7
Nine = 8
Ten = 9
Jack = 10
Queen = 11
King = 12
Ace = 13
# chooses a random card 
score = 0 # score at game start
def scores(): # this will print out the current high scores.
    print "The current scores in file: %r" % filename
    print txt.read() # prints the open txt file

def start(): # this is sent after the scores. welcomes play to game.
    print "Welcome %s, the computer and you will both draw a card. Whoever gets the higher card wins" % name
    print "Try to in a row to go on the high scores!"
    print "Good luck %s" % name
    game() #starts the game

def game(): # begins the actual game
    print "The dealer draws a card..." 
    dealer = random.choice([Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King, Ace]) # gives the dealer a random card
    print "You draw a card..."
    user = random.choice([Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King, Ace]) # gives the user a random card
    if dealer > user: # if dealer wins 
        print "You lose!"
        if score > 1: # checks if score is better than 1, then writes score to txt doc
            filename.write("\n")
            filename.write(name "=" score)
            filename.close()
        else: # aren't good enough, game quits
            print "You didn't get a score over 1, you suck and aren't going to be on high scores."
            filename.close()
    elif user < dealer: # if user wins
        print "Nice! You won that round"
        score = score + 1 # adds 1 to current score
        game() # next round
    else:
        print "Um no idea what you did there, again?"
        game()

scores() # score def
name = raw_input("First off let's get your name. \n >") # asks the users name for recording high scores
start() # start def
```

Comment: In your `else` part, you say `"Um no idea what you did there, again?"`. Looking at the if statements, when they have a tie, it gets here.

Comment: Save scores by opening file f= open('scores.txt', 'w') . Then write with f.write('score'). When finished remember to close the file f.close().

Comment: In the `game` function you directly wrote to the file **without** opening it. Also when you do `filename.write(name "=" score)` the program raises an error because `name "=" score` is three **distinct** strings. You need to add  the `+` operator between the strings.

Comment: @ NegativeFeedbackLoop, Shadex wants to add to the file so if you use `"w"` mode then all the previous content of the file will be replaced by the text which he added in the end. The file will end up having only the last score. In such a case `"a"` mode or append mode is needed. You should check out this link: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help, learnt a lot!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Opening the file:

```
txt = open(filename)
```

In python there are 3 types of opening a file. Reading, writing and appending. You specify them with 'r', 'w' and 'a' as the second argument of the open-function:

```
txt = open(filename, 'r')
```

But if you want to read-write a file, like in this card-game, you have to use the 'r+' (or 'w+' and 'a+'). Then you can also read-write instead of only read this file.

2) Invalid syntax:

```
filename.write(name "=" score)
```

You should write:

```
filename.write("%s=%d" % (name, score))
```

3) 'score' variable:

In the game function an error raises:

```
    if score > 1: # checks if score is better than 1, then writes score to txt doc
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'score' referenced before assignment
```

You have to set the score variable to a global variable (inside the game function). So the scope is not only used for the game function itself:

```
global score
```

4) Small mistake in "game-logic":

In your if-else statement you do this:

```
if dealer > user:
    ...
elif user < dealer:
    ...
else
```

The elif-condition is the same as the if-condition. You have to change it to this:

```
if dealer > user:
    ...
elif user > dealer:
    ...
else
```

5) Read write file:

You wrote for example:

```
filename.write("\n")
```

But the filename only is a string. You have to use the 'txt'-variable which is returned by the open() function.

```
txt.write("\n")
```

**After all these changes, the code looks like this:**

```
from sys import argv # imports the opening of two separate files
import random # imports the 'random' string
script, filename = argv # sets two variables, one on the py file and the other on the txt file
txt = open(filename, 'r+') # opens the txt file

# card variables assigning values 
Two = 1
Three = 2
Four = 3
Five = 4
Six = 5
Seven = 6
Eight = 7
Nine = 8
Ten = 9
Jack = 10
Queen = 11
King = 12
Ace = 13
# chooses a random card 
score = 0 # score at game start
def scores(): # this will print out the current high scores.
    print "The current scores in file: %r" % filename
    print txt.read() # prints the open txt file

def start(): # this is sent after the scores. welcomes play to game.
    print "Welcome %s, the computer and you will both draw a card. Whoever gets the higher card wins" % name
    print "Try to in a row to go on the high scores!"
    print "Good luck %s" % name
    game() #starts the game

def game(): # begins the actual game
    global score
    print "The dealer draws a card..." 
    dealer = random.choice([Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King, Ace]) # gives the dealer a random card
    print "You draw a card..."
    user = random.choice([Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King, Ace]) # gives the user a random card
    if dealer > user: # if dealer wins 
        print "You lose!"
        if score > 1: # checks if score is better than 1, then writes score to txt doc
            txt.write("\n")
            txt.write("%s=%d" % (name, score))
            txt.close()
        else: # aren't good enough, game quits
            print "You didn't get a score over 1, you suck and aren't going to be on high scores."
            txt.close()
    elif user > dealer: # if user wins
        print "Nice! You won that round"
        score = score + 1 # adds 1 to current score
        game() # next round
    else:
        print "Um no idea what you did there, again?"
        game()

scores() # score def
name = raw_input("First off let's get your name. \n >") # asks the users name for recording high scores
start() # start def
```

I hope that I can help you!

Comment: Thanks so much for this help, that all worked pretty much, but sometimes i run into an error "IOError: [Errno 0] Error" I feel like it could be to do with when the player and dealer ties.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't reproduce the error... if you get it again, could you post the whole text? Maybe this would be helpful.

Another information: in your game where you use ```random.choic([Two, Three, ..., Ace])```, you could instead use ```random.choice(range(1, 14))```. ```range``` creates an array from 1 to 13. So you don't have to initialize the variables and write them again in the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write to a file, you should open it in write mode:

```
txt = open(filename, mode='w')
```

Comment: But when i change the file to write, i can't read it out in my scores def

Comment: Use mode='rw', then you can do both